# Conditiional probability as mean of gaussian?

Tags: normal-distribution, mean

I am reading the paper "Tutorial of Variational Auto-Encoder" and I faced the following notation:
$$P(z) =  \mathcal{N}(z\mid 0,I)$$
$z$ is a latent variable which should have been normal distributed. But I don't understand what the mean is? What does $z\mid 0$ as the mean imply? Is the mean of the gaussian $P(z\mid 0)$? If so, what does it the probability of $z$ given the probability of $0$ mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That notation is common in many places in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.05908.pdf), e.g. Page 3, third sentence from the last states that $f(z;\theta)$ is the mean and $\sigma^2I$ is the covariance matrix of the random variable's PDF represented by the expression: $\mathcal{N}(X|f(z;\theta),\sigma^2I)$. Similarly, in your case, $z$ is zero-mean and has identity covariance. Don't think it as $z|0$. It doesn't mean *given*, as in $P(A|B)$.

Comment: If in the first case $f(z;\theta)$ is the mean, then why it was not written $\mathcal{N}(f(z;\theta),\sigma^2I)$. And if in the second case it is zero mean why it is not written: $\mathcal{N}(0,I)$?

Comment: That's the notation that the paper follows for defining PDFs. Apparently, it chooses to embed the RV into the notation of $\mathcal{N}$. If you look at Page 5, last sentence, he reserves the notation $\mathcal{N}(0,I)$ for referring to RVs, not PDFs.

Comment: do you some statistic book which could help me understand and strengenth this basic elements which you are able to answer?

Comment: I think reviewing from different books is better. Because notations change, but concepts don’t. After you see different notations of the same thing, you start to focus on the concept.